# Crontab Linux executar Script PHP numa periodicidade menor que 1 minuto

Tags: ubuntu, linux

Por gentileza preciso executar o crontab para que execute a cada 1 segundo , deve executar um script .php no servidor Linux Debian.

- - - - - root /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cloudns.php

ao executar manual, ele executa numa boa, mais adicionando ai no crontab ele não executa a cada 1 minuto.

Por gentileza, se alguém poder me auxiliar , me ajudaria muito e fico agradecido desde já! Um abraço.

Comment: Explica aí pq vc quer rodar esse script 1 vez por segundo...  apenas por curiosidade. Às vezes há uma solução melhor q colocar o q vc quer fazer num programa php (interpretado) na crontab.

Answer (score 1):

A granularidade do cron é de 60 segundos, portanto, por vias "normais" não é possível realizar o que pretende, a cada 1 segundo.

Uma solução é contornar com o próprio PHP.

Uma ideia, que inclusive é adotada por diversos frameworks como o Laravel, **por exemplo** é, invocar o cron a cada 1 minuto (esse tempo é variável, definido pelo usuário).

O cron executaria, a cada minuto, o script PHP.

Dentro do script PHP controla-se um "loop infinito" com pausas de 1 segundo.

Assim conseguirá o que deseja.

Se quiser pode prolongar, fazendo com que o cron execute a cada 5 minutos. Nesse esquema o script PHP ficaria rodando por 300 segundos, ou seja 300 iterações.

Claro que para isso é recomendado que tenha um segundo script PHP que é o que fará as iterações em background.

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa é que crontab executa o período mínimo de **1 em 1 minuto**.Então vou lhe explicar como faz nesse período 
O crontab não roda com o nome de usuário.
**Não é recomendado usar o root parta o crontab** mas se mesmo assim você quiser dê o comando:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Assim você vai crirar/editar uma tabela crontab para o usuário root.
Depois adicione essa linha no editor e coloca isso:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cloudns.php
```

Comment: fazendo testes.... vi algo na internet do comando: sleep tempo_em_segundos &&    , confere?

Comment: Confere. Eu não imagino um negócio rodando de segundo em segundo. Uma opção é você rodar o script quando inicia, e dentro do script vc fazer um loop infinito...

Answer (score 0):

Para executar um script a cada um segundo, você pode combinar a função while jogando em background o processo, por exemplo:

```
while -n1 " /usr/bin/php5 -q /var/www/cloudns.php" &
```

E aí o processo ficará rodando a cada um segundo até você matar ele com o `kill`, ou reiniciar a máquina.